# Gridview Won't Updated Android

Tags: android, gridview

So I put an images inside of gridview, it works fine when the beginning and showing 20 images but when I try to show less than that it won't updated.
there are a condition when the gridview updated, it's updated when I load 20 images but when I try to load less or zero it wont updated.

how do I resolve this ?

here is my code on the adapter

```
 private final Context context;
private List<Movie> urls = new ArrayList<>();

public MovieGridViewAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> urls) {
    this.context = context;
    this.urls = urls;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (urls.size() == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return urls.size();
}

@Override
public Movie getItem(int position) {
    return urls.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View gridView = view;
    if (gridView == null) {
        gridView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_poster, viewGroup, false);
    }
    ImageView posterImageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.posterImageView);

    // Get the image URL for the current position.
    Movie movie = getItem(position);

    //needed to append the image url
    String imageBaseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";

    Picasso.with(context) //
            .load(imageBaseUrl+movie.getPosterPath()) //
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_hourglass_empty_black_24dp) //
            .error(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp) //
            .fit() //
            .tag(context) //
            .into(posterImageView);

    Log.v("jalan ji", "jalan");
    return gridView;
}
```

here is where I try to update the Gridview

```
List<Favorite> favorites = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_TITLE);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_TITLE));

        try{
            Favorite fav = new Favorite();
            fav.setId(id);
            fav.setTitle(title);
            favorites.add(fav);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for(Favorite favorite : favorites){
        Call<MovieSingle> call = movieDbClient.getMovie(favorite.getId(), apiKey);
        setTitle("Favorite Movies");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieSingle>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MovieSingle> call, @NonNull Response<MovieSingle> response) {
                Movie mov = new Movie();
                mov.setBackdropPath(response.body().getBackdrop_path());
                mov.setOverview(response.body().getOverview());
                mov.setReleaseDate(response.body().getRelease_date());
                mov.setTitle(response.body().getTitle());
                mov.setVoteAverage(response.body().getVote_average());
                mov.setPosterPath(response.body().getPoster_path());
                movie.add(mov);
                Log.v("berhasil", " "+response.body().getTitle());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MovieSingle> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.v("gagal", "berhasil");
                showErrorMessage();
            }
        });
    }

    showGridView();
    pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    MovieGridViewAdapter movieGridViewAdapter = new MovieGridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), movie);
    Log.v("Test", movie.get(2).getTitle());
    Log.v("Test", movie.get(2).getPosterPath());
    movieGridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    gridView.invalidateViews();
    gridView.setAdapter(movieGridViewAdapter);
```

and the layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgdetail">

    <GridView android:id="@+id/movieitem_grid"
              android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:columnWidth="165dp"

              android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
              android:scrollbars="none"
              android:listSelector="@null"
              android:numColumns="auto_fit"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_error"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:text="@string/error_msg"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: No errors? Just not updating?

Comment: @Barns52 yes, just not updating

Comment: Can you post the activity class ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I have to put the setAdapter method inside the loop and create new variable of list and make it final, can't use the global one. so the final code should look like this

```
List<Favorite> favorites = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<Movie> movie1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MovieContract.MovieEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_TITLE);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_MOVIE_ID));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MovieContract.MovieEntry.COLUMN_TITLE));

        try{
            Favorite fav = new Favorite();
            fav.setId(id);
            fav.setTitle(title);
            favorites.add(fav);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for(Favorite favorite : favorites){
        Call<MovieSingle> call = movieDbClient.getMovie(favorite.getId(), apiKey);
        setTitle("Favorite Movies");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieSingle>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MovieSingle> call, @NonNull Response<MovieSingle> response) {
                Movie mov = new Movie();
                mov.setBackdropPath(response.body().getBackdrop_path());
                mov.setOverview(response.body().getOverview());
                mov.setReleaseDate(response.body().getRelease_date());
                mov.setTitle(response.body().getTitle());
                mov.setVoteAverage(response.body().getVote_average());
                mov.setPosterPath(response.body().getPoster_path());
                movie1.add(mov);
                showGridView();
                pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                MovieGridViewAdapter movieGridViewAdapter = new MovieGridViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), movie1);
                movieGridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                gridView.setAdapter(movieGridViewAdapter);
                Log.v("berhasil", " "+movie1.get(0).getTitle());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MovieSingle> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.v("gagal", "berhasil");
                showErrorMessage();
            }
        });
    }
```